# Como resolver error "Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project" usando netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, spring-boot, maven

Este es el archivo pom.xml, he visto muchos foros con el mismo problema ,donde les dices que deben corregir este archivo pero por mas que intento no funciona.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejemplo01</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ejemplo01</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                                
    </properties>   
             
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplication.properties ,donde se llama el jdbc.

server.servlet.contextPath=/ejemplo01
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ejemploserverTimezone=UTC sprint.datasource.username=root
sprint.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Ejemplo01AplicationTest.java

```
package com.example.ejemplo01;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class Ejemplo01ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: En tu caso desde el pom no deberías tener errores porque lo has generado con spring-boot, la mayoría de veces con este error es por plugins mal gestionados pero no es tu caso porque solo necesitas `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, te recomiendo que ejecutes desde la consola `mvn clean install` para verificar.

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, cuando ejecuto esos comandos la consola me dice que no los reconoce como comando interno o externo, al parecer no están instalados, como debo instalarlos.....he visto que configuran la variable PATH, es realmente necesario? existe otra forma de hacerlo a través de NetBeans? si debo configurar la variable PATH me puedes decir como hacerlo exactamente?

Comment: Si no lo tienes configurado puedes revisar tu carpeta de proyecto y seguramente tendrás un archivo `mvnw.cmd` que en pocas palabras en como un scrip que ejecuta maven sin tenerlo instalado solo cambia el comando de `mvn` a `mvnw`, entonces desde `PowerShell` en windows puedes ejecutar `./mvnw clean install`.

Comment: Hola despues de ejecutar el comando en powershell me arrojo errores, adjunto la imagen en la pregunta que editare. Marca un error en el archivo Ejemplo01AplicationTest. y también menciona al sobre el controlador jdbc. En la pregunta principal adjunto los archivos mencionados

Comment: El error que tienes es por la dependencia `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, no tienes configurada la conexión de la base de datos en el `application.properties` si quitas esa dependencia podrás iniciar el proyecto sin problema o configura la conexión con una base de datos existente.

Comment: Hola, por mas que configuro el documento sigue el error, si tienes un código de esa configuración te agradecería, eliminándolo tampoco funciona, también intente colocar la dependencia que falta en el pom y funciono al principio, después de seguir avanzando con el proyecto volvía a salir el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo como lo solucioné luego de tres meses de sufrimiento.

En el directorio donde tenía el proyecto había una carpeta en la ruta con tilde en el nombre "Programación".

Solo tuve que quitarle la tilde y listo, se me solucionó.

Espero te sirva o a alguien que estuvo buscando tanto tiempo como yo.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tuve este problema en ubuntu, y era porque el archivo mvnw no estaba como ejecutable.
Solución:
interfaz grafica: click derecho -> propiedades -> permisos -> hacer ejecutable.
en terminal (en la carpeta del proyecto): `chmod +x mvnw`

Answer (score 0):

quizá ya es demasiado tarde, pero dejo aquí mi solución por si a alguien le sirve. Lo que me ocurrió es que al ejecutar el comando:

mvn clean javafx:run

en la carpeta raíz de mi proyecto (donde está el pom.xml) todo funcionaba excelente. Pero cuando fui a netBeans v17. me lanzaba ese mismo error.

Le dí click derecho al proyecto > Actions
y en la casilla donde se encuentra "Run project" coloqué el comando
clean javafx:run.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mismo comando que genera netbeans en el archivo nbactions.xml para ejecutar el proyecto en la etiqueta 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso solucionó mi problema, ya que aveces el editor asigna esa labor de ejecución a org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:exec. Y no siempre funciona para todos los proyectos

Answer (score 0):

En mi clase de modelo "Cliente" estaba utilizando "int" para mysql, siendo el correcto "Integer". Asimismo, debes limpiar y compilar tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso este problema se logró solucionar al especificar la Main Class en las propiedades del proyecto.

Click derecho en el proyecto > Properties > Run
Aquí se debe definir la Main Class, para esto seleccionamos "Browse" y elegimos la que corresponda a nuestro proyecto.

Espero esta solución ayude a quien lo necesite.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, en el archivo pom.xml la siguiente línea tenía el nombre de la clase main erróneo porque yo lo había modificado.

```
<exec.mainClass>com.poo.bingo.simulator.{nombre del archivo}</exec.mainClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

yo tenía la tilde en un comentario, dentro del `aplication.properties`, y tenía el mismo problema, me abriste los ojos